# How to generate typescript types(not interfaces) from JSON object

Tags: json, typescript

I found a lot of online tools and VS Code extensions for generating typescript **interfaces** from **JSON** object, but I don't find any for generating **types** from **JSON** object(I know that there isn't significant difference between both).

Simple example

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "logging": {
      "path" : "logs",
      "extension" : "json"
    }
  }
}
```

Becomes:

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface Logging {
        path: string;
        extension: string;
    }

    export interface Configuration {
        logging: Logging;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        configuration: Configuration;
    }

}
```

What I need is:

```
declare module namespace {

    export type Configuration = {
      logging: Logging
    };

    export type Logging = {
      path: string,
      extension: string,
   };

    export type RootObject {
      configuration: Configuration;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason you "need" types. For such basic object types, there is little meaningful difference between a type alias and an interface.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, they are more suitable for me when are used for data objects with no behavior. Anyways, s a matter of preference.

Comment: Not really, `interfaces` don't need to be implemented by a class, you can have object literals assign to an interface just as to a type alias.. there really is no difference https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGQgHMjkiBBOAbwFgAoORuMTGACwC44BnGKMgNz0mcUKiTcEEJF178kRIXQC+9ejACeYPIRJkAQnAC81YUxbtZfQWcZjgEqTJ7WFS1XXoAbYPExddUgVKE1oGJntHaS4AIhiAGltmVk44OPoPNTofeAAjAOIgokNQpMjJaLSEpItU9JUgA

Comment: I know that and how I said is a matter of preference. I don't see a particular reason not to use types.

Comment: I don't dispute the preference, sure you can use whichever you want I was quibbling with the " they are more suitable for me when are used for data objects", which I am not sure why they would be more suitable. My point being that if the code is generated I wouldn't much care if they were interfaces or type aliases. If it's just a matter of preference the of course you are dree to have your preferences :),